# Use USBIP for devices that are being removed and reconnected

Tags: usb, usb-device, hot-plug

I am using usbip and a raspberry pi to extend the range of a wireless keyboard to a computer that is just a tad too far away for the keyboard to work reliably on its own.

Sometimes the USB receiver of the keyboard is reconnected and used elsewhere, but when it is reconnected to the raspberry pi the USBIP connection is not automatically re-established.

How can I achieve automatic reconnection?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When a device that is bound and attached remotely is unplugged, the device is automatically detached on the client and unbound on the host. After that the state is the same as if it was never bound or attached.

The usbip commands for binding (on the host) and attaching (on the client) may be run repeatedly with the same arguments. While this issues an error message on already bound or attached devices, nothing bad happens! So one can just install background scripts that will repeatedly bind and attach the devices. Example scripts and systemd units are provided below. Be sure to change the Hostname and Port IDs to your needs.

### Host

Skript `/opt/usbip/usbip-bind`:

```
#!/bin/bash

SPOOL=/var/spool/usbip/bind

if [[ $1 == "-q" ]]
then
    exec &>/dev/null
fi

touch $SPOOL

while [[ -e $SPOOL ]]
do
  /usr/bin/usbip bind -b 1-1.2.1
  /usr/bin/usbip bind -b 1-1.2.2
  sleep 10
done

/usr/bin/usbip unbind -b 1-1.2.1
/usr/bin/usbip unbind -b 1-1.2.2

exit 0
```

Systemd unit `/etc/systemd/system/usbip-bind.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=USB-IP Bindings

[Service]
ExecStart=/opt/usbip/usbip-bind -q
ExecStop=/bin/rm /var/spool/usbip/bind  ; /bin/bash -c "while [[ -d /proc/"$MAINPID" ]]; do sleep 1; done"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Be sure do make the directory `/var/spool/usbip`. Then enable and start the unit:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl enable usbip-bind
systemctl start usbip-bind
```

### Client

Skript `/opt/usbip/usbip-attach`:

```
#!/bin/bash

SPOOL=/var/spool/usbip/attach

if [[ $1 == "-q" ]]
then
    exec &>/dev/null
fi

touch $SPOOL

while [[ -e $SPOOL ]]
do
    /usr/bin/usbip attach -r pi -b 1-1.2.1
    /usr/bin/usbip attach -r pi -b 1-1.2.2
    sleep 10
done

/usr/bin/usbip detach -p 0
/usr/bin/usbip detach -p 1

exit 0
```

Systemd unit `/etc/systemd/system/usbip-attach.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=USB-IP Attach
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/opt/usbip/usbip-attach -q
ExecStop=/bin/rm /var/spool/usbip/attach  ;  /bin/bash -c "while [[ -d /proc/"$MAINPID" ]]; do sleep 1; done"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Be sure do make the directory `/var/spool/usbip`. Then enable and start the unit:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl enable usbip-attach
systemctl start usbip-attach
```

Now you may remove the device whenever needed and at most 20 seconds after plugging it back in the usbip connection is reestablished.

Comment: Binding on usbip host can be done using udev rules and a simple `lsusb | grep "vendor_id:product_id"` script

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it kind of work.. there are a few more this you have to do.

First:

You have to make the scipts runnable on both host and client

```
sudo chmod +x /opt/usbip/usbip-attach
sudo chmod +x /opt/usbip/usbip-bind
```

In my case usbip was not installed in `/opt/usbip`, I had to simply write just `usbip` in both host and client service file.

I also had to start the `usbipd` service. So on host i used this file instead:

```
[Unit]
Description=USB-IP Bindings

[Service]
ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/usbipd -D
ExecStart=/opt/usbip/usbip-bind -q
ExecStop=/bin/rm /var/spool/usbip/bind  ; /bin/bash -c "while [[ -d /proc/"$MAINPID" ]]; do sleep 1; done"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

It starts the usbipd server first

and in both host and client files i had to remove `/usr/bin/`

After these changes it worked fine on my Raspberry Pi host and ubuntu 19.10 client

Answer (score 0):

Although my answer is quite late, but maybe useful for the others: https://github.com/alpertsev/usbip-service-shell

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please note that [link-only answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) are discouraged, as the link may become invalid or the linked content change. Please edit your answer to include at least a summary of how to use the tool referenced in the link.